# PowerBI - DateAdd with max

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to add days in the date field but I always have the same error, my field "event_date" is date. I don't know what's wrong

Error

[image]

```
userActive =
var datamaxx = CONVERT (CALCULATE (max (table1 [event_date])), DATETIME)
var dad = DATEADD (DATE (YEAR (datamaxx), MONTH (datamaxx), DAY ((datamaxx))), 1, DAY)
```

or

```
userActive =
var datamaxx = CONVERT (CALCULATE (max (table1 [event_date])), DATETIME)
var dad = DATEADD (datamaxx, 1, DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a measure or a calculated column?

I simplified the below by removing the CALCULATE and also adding in the RETURN statement, you must RETURN a value when you have a multi-statement DAX formula.

Note [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dateadd-function-dax) returns a column of dates.

```
userActive = 
var datamaxx = TODAY()
RETURN DATE(YEAR(datamaxx), MONTH(datamaxx), DAY(datamaxx) + 1)
```

Comment: I try create the CALCULATE, I did that commented but the error remains in the variable (datamaxx) "Parameter is not correct type"

Comment: I tried to use today () but even so, error

userActive =
var datamaxx = TODAY ()
return
DATEADD (datamaxx, 1, DAY)

Comment: See my edit to my answer. I have tested an it works.

Answer (score 0):

You said your **event_date** column is a date. Not sure why you are trying to CONVERT it to DATETIME again! This is going to just add 00:00:00 to the time part in the column.

Second, why your are dividing the DateTime value into YEAR, MONTH & DATE to create a DATE value where as the variable already holding value of DATETIME type?

Now, if your only intension is to add 1 day with the current date value and wants to store the value in a new **Measure**, you can create this below measure simply-

```
date+1 = max (table1[event_date]) + 1
```

This +1 will increase your date value by 1 day. This will work as you said your source column's data type is **date**.